# При парсинге, один блок берется, а другой нет, хотя меняю только название классов

Tags: java, парсер

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт на JAVA https://www.moyareklama.ru/%D0%91%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8/
Один блок берется, а другой нет, хотя в регулярном выражении меняется только класс.

```
String regExp = "<div class=\\\"adv-list-title\\\">(.*?)</div>";
```

Comment: зачем разбирать его регулярками. возьмите JSoup или другое готовое решение для парсинга

Comment: @МихаилРебров, просто уже есть написанный код, и там используется регулярное выражение. А с помощью JSoup, я уже сделал куда удобнее. Прост с этим хочу разобраться.